# Javascript import not working

Tags: javascript, webstorm

Here's a piece of javascript in which I import another javascript file located in a different directory. The function in the file does not get called from this script. The toggle function works fine and the directory of the file is correct.

```
<script src = "../public/javascripts/DivManipulations.js">
    </script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("button").click(function () {
                $("h1").toggle();
                test("Hi"); // This is the function that is not getting called.
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Here's the script in the other file.

```
function test(message){
    Window.alert(message);
}
```

I am working in Webstorm and the "alert" function is highlighted and it shows "Unresolved function or method alert".

Comment: And what are the errors in your console?

Comment: Console? This is happening on the client side. No errors on the server side though.

Comment: Browsers have a console that will log javascript messages and errors. [See here](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8525/how-to-open-the-javascript-console-in-different-browsers)

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive. In browsers, `alert` is a method of the (all-lowercase) `window` object, not the `Window` (with a capital W) object.

Answer (score 1):

if `window.alert(message);` (lower case) still not resolved, please check if 'HTML' library is enabled in Settings/JavaScript/Libraries

Comment: Enabled where? In the browser?

Comment: no, in WebStorm. You are working in WebStorm, and 'alert' is shown is not resolved there. So what does this have to do with your browser settings?

Comment: strange... Please can you attach a sample project that shows up the problem?

Comment: Hi, I've also been discussing the same problem in this question - its framed differently. maybe you can understand it better there. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193062/javascript-references-from-ejs-file-not-working-on-webstorm