# Javascript references from EJS file not working on Webstorm

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webstorm

I am working on a Node.JS project in Webstorm, where there is a main EJS file with some javascript that is supposed to call a function in another javascript file. When the HTML renders, the call does not get made, to the function in the other javascript file. I know the path reference to the javascript file is correct because webstorm automatically changes it if I move the file in the navigation bar.

Here's the calling code in the main EJS file.

```
<script src = "../public/javascripts/DivManipulations.js">
</script>
<script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            remoteScriptTest("Hi");
        });
    });

</script>
```

Here's the code in the function being called.

```
function remoteScriptTest(message){
    window.alert(message);
}
```

I realize this may not be sufficient information to solve the problem, so please ask for whatever that may be helpful.

Comment: Console says: "Uncaught Reference Error: remoteSriptTest is not defined". I don't understand what else I need to do to get it to work.

Comment: It contains the function. How do I check its "loaded"?

Comment: Here's an interesting observation: Requesting the javascript file returns the calling html file from the server - which by the way is written in ejs. That's why the function is not defined. Any clue why this should happen? This is a nodejs server developing with webstorm

Comment: not sure what your application looks like.. is it an express application with client files in public folder, served like 'app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'))'? You need to set your URLs relative to 'public' folder then - so try changing URL in your EJS to <script src = "/javascripts/DivManipulations.js">

Comment: yes its express! I have not explicitly specified the static folder, but making it relative to the "public" folder is not working either. Whats the default folder?

Comment: Default folder seems to be the root folder. Making the path relative to the "public" folder, nothing gets retrieved at all.

Answer (score 0):

try to remove public from the include path.. I had the same problem.

```
<script src = "/javascripts/DivManipulations.js">
```