# Javascript file is not being retrieved in NodeJS / Express project being developed in Webstorm

Tags: node.js, express, webstorm

I'm working on a NodeJS project with Express in Webstorm. I'm making a reference to a Javascript file from an EJS(HTML) file.

```
<script src = "public/javascripts/DivManipulations.js">
</script>
```

But the file that Chrome retrieves is the same EJS file instead of Javascript. I'm not sure why this is happaning.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><%= title %></title>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css'/>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script src = "public/javascripts/DivManipulations.js">
</script>
<script>


    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            $("h1").toggle(); //This toggle part works
            remoteScriptTest("Hi"); //This remoteSrciptTest does not.
        });
    });

    function testCall(){
        window.alert("Hi");
    }

</script>
</head>
<body style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">
<div id="root"></div>

<div style="background-color: red; width: 100px; height: 60px; overflow: auto;">
    <span>Some text comes here</span>
</div>

<h1><%= title %> </h1>
</p>  Welcome to <%= title %> </p>
<button>Click here</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the js file:

```
/**
 * Created by ---- on 11/21/13.
 */

function remoteScriptTest(message){
    window.alert(message);
}
```

Here's the package.json

```
{
      "name": "application-name",
      "version": "0.0.1",
      "private": true,
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node app.js"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "express": "3.4.4",
        "ejs": "*"
      }
    }
```

Comment: isn't it the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20193062/javascript-references-from-ejs-file-not-working-on-webstorm? Have you read my last comment there?

Comment: It will help if you post your Express.js code for the static middleware.

Comment: @lena yes it is! I've read your comments too, but the problem persists. Have you read my last two comments after yours? I posted this question to frame it differently hoping somebody else would identify with the problem.

Comment: well, it seems we can't proceed without your code, sorry. I have run out of ideas:(

Comment: @lena Thanks for being persistently helpful. I've pasted all the code I have. Please let me know if you something else.

Comment: I'm sorry, but your server-side code  (app.js) is needed, so that I get an idea on the way you serve your client files

Comment: @lena I just fixed it! Thanks though.